# Windows's notification area doesn't allow to hide icons, when all are shown

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, notifications, notification-area

I'm using the option to "Always show all icons in the notification are", because it is easier for me to see them on one line.

But, when that option is selected I can't choose anymore which of the icons should still appear, which is very annoying.

Is it possible after selecting "Always show all icons in the notification are" to disable selected ones somehow?

[image]

Comment: Turn it off, de-select any you wish, then turn it back on?

Comment: Are you connected to a active directory domain?

Comment: @Moab Tried, but didn't work.

Comment: @Ramhound No, I'm not connected